# Sectioned RecyclerView in mvvmcross android

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, android-recyclerview, mvvmcross

I'm trying to make a RecyclerView look like the following [Sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xuJB.png)

I'm using mvvmcross and the xml I have so far is this:

```
<MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    fab:MvxBind="ItemsSource EmballageGroups"
    fab:MvxTemplateSelector="Hocras.OnRoute.Droid.TypeTemplateSelector,Hocras.OnRoute.Droid" />
```

But this is a simple list without sections. How do I get sections in there? (it has to be sectioned per product type)

Comment: means do  you want to expand each section its self or you want to show Hadar for each section.

Comment: @Chetan First I need to make a section and then I want a header for each section that has items!

Comment: do you  know about Expandable ListView.

Comment: @Chetan No I do not. Not a experienced android/xamarin dev

Comment: please find my answer Expandable ListView is core android view to create section listview with expand and collapse listener .

Comment: @Chetan I'm trying it out right now. Will let you know if it works for me

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the sample here https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/WorkingWithCollections

It uses `MvxExpandableListView`

```
<Mvx.MvxExpandableListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_kitten"
    local:MvxGroupItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_expandablegroup"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource KittenGroups" />
```

Comment: Will the template selector I made work? since I need different item layouts per group.

Answer (score 1):

Android ExpandableListView is a view that shows items in a vertically scrolling two-level list. It differs from a ListView by allowing two levels which are groups that can be easily expanded and collapsed by touching to view and their respective children items.
ExpandableListViewAdapter in android loads the data into the items associated with this view.

Following are some important methods that are used by this class :
please find complete information into below link

[Android ExpandableListView](http://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial)